# Is the set of matrices with rank at most $r$ closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

The question is as follows: $\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$

> Is the set $S_r = \{A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}: \rank(A) \leq r\}$ closed in $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$ in the Euclidean topology?

I have a feeling that this is true, but I got stuck looking for a convincing argument.  Certainly this is true for $r = n-1$.  Perhaps it can be shown that $S_{r-1}$ is a closed subset of $S_r$?

No neat tricks are coming to mind, but I would think that there must be one. This seems like the kind of thing that has a canonical answer, so links are welcome.

Comment: Thanks @Sam! Couldn't find it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the application
$$
f_k(M) = (\det M_{-i_1 \dots -i_k; -j_1 \dots -j_k})_{1\le i_1 <\dots < i_k\le n;1\le j_1 <\dots < j_k\le n}
$$
where $ M_{-i_1 \dots -i_k; -j_1 \dots -j_k}$ is the matrix $M$ without the lines 
$i_a$ and without the columns $j_b$.

Hence $$\text{rank }M \le r\iff
M\in \bigcap_{k = r+1}^n f_k^{-1}(\{0\})
$$

Hence this set is closed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\operatorname{rank}(A)\le r$ if and only if the determinant of any $k\times k$ submatrix of $A$ vanishes for $k>r$.